# Git - history only the last 10 commits?

Tags: git, shell, gitea

I work at a shell script which commits automatically my last changes from my project to my local git repository. It works great so my next step is to optimize the script. Now I search for a command to delete the history of my repository except for the last 10 commits.

I only found commands to clean the whole history, that is not the solution I want. Maybe someone had an idea?

Comment: What do you mean "optimize the script"? Why do you want to delete your history?

Comment: Because I want to delete a lot of test commits and also I want to reduce the size of my repository. With every commit I save the database if something has change (the database isn't very large)

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to rebase your commit history. Rebasing lets you clean up and prettify your history.

Comment: Storing a database in Git is a bit of a red flag, though. Git is for code, not data. It might not be the right tool for whatever job you're having it do.

Comment: Thanks I will look for rebasing. (I learned git only a few weeks ago). I read about the problem for data saving in git, but I don't find a better way at now. But that is another thematic :). Thanks for your answers.